# use EF4.1 Code First DbContext with 2 Connection Strings

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

is it possible to have one DbContext with 2 connection strings ?

this is what I have:

```
// this is from Db1
public class Log
{
   public virtual Court Court {get;set;}
   public Guid CourtId {get;set;}
   public DateTime Date{get;set;}
}

// this is from Db2 (different connection string)
public class Court
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

is this doable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have two connection strings to different databases (containing different tables) you must have two different contexts containing their own mappings. This is true for both ObjectContext API and DbContext API - it is by design. The only supported scenario is having two connection strings two exactly same databases on the same type of database server (database provider). In such case you can pass connection string to the context's constructor when instancing it. Even in this scenario you cannot have one context instance working with two database connections.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so. No way jose. It just does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The DbContext class only supports one connection per context. One of the issues with allowing a single DbContext to use multiple databases would be query generation. In your example, what kind of query would allow me to a list of all Logs, given the Court entity is housed in a different database?

Comment: well, for something like logs.Select(o => new{o.Court.Name, o.Date}) it would be one query in the first Db asking for the logs, and one in the second asking for the courts, and than they would be connected in memory by CourtId ( that's how I imagined this)